# Походження слова "нари"

Tags: етимологія

[Нари](http://sum.in.ua/s/nary) - настил, поміст або якийсь пристрій для спання (перев. з дерев'яних дощок), що міститься на певній відстані від підлоги.

Цікавить звідки в українській мові взялося це слово, а саме чи  не є це калькою російського слова "нары". Нажаль, пошуки в [ЕСУМі](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_2003/EtSlUkrM_2003.pdf) не дали ніякого результату, а точніше там пише, що походження невідоме (проте, на російській [Вікіпедії](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B) є припущення:  русск. нары, укр. нари, польск. mary, nary та інші, порівнюють із нім. Bahre «носилки; гріб», пояснюючи перехід b > n, m зближенням з «мертвий»). Чи можлива така версія?

Answer (score 2):

Те шчо польське ***mary*** походить **від** середнӧверхнӧнїмецького ***bāre*** (*bahre*) — *ноші*, навіть як [*паланкін*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BD); і старочеськe *mary* — *ноші для мертвих* — є посередником — **правда**, хоча б так [затверџує WSJP](http://wsjp.pl/do_druku.php?id_hasla=27762&id_znaczenia=5193903).

Поза тим нема *nary*, лиш иншиь *Słownik etymologiczny języka polskiego · Aleksander Brückner* вказує, шчо польське слово [nary](https://pl.wikisource.org/wiki/S%C5%82ownik_etymologiczny_j%C4%99zyka_polskiego/nary):

> <sub>міь переклад</sub>
>
> *записане в 1570 не є руським (ч: украӥнським) запозиченям, хоча сӧгоднї (1927?) на Русї (ч: Украӥні) красше знане.*

Красше знане, оскільки для польської слово [*prycza*](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prycza) (шчо від [*Pritsche*](https://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pritsche#Pritsche_(j%C4%99zyk_niemiecki))) поширеніше, аніж *nary*. Також варто зазначити, шчо [*mary*](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary) взагалі має иншого значіня як *ноші для мертвих, катафалк*. Тоь ж SEJP про *mary* зі згаданим в запитанї переходу *b*–*m*:

> **mary**, ‘nosze umarłego’, z niem. *Bahre*, do nas przez Czechów w 15. wieku; pod wpływem nagłosu *m-* wedle *mór*, odmieniono *b-* w *m-*; niem. *Bahre* od pnia *bher-*, ‘nieść’ (p. brać).

Отже сє слово зʼявило ся десь на вік ранїше, однак **немаʼ достовірного звʼязку між *nary* i *mary***.

Таким чином, припустєнє залишаєть ся недостовірним припустєнєм, сєбто невстановлена форма, і потребує в подальшому науковому дослїџенї.

Answer (score 0):

Етимологічний слоаник української мови том 4,ст. 43

[image]

Comment: скажіть, будь ласка, чому ви видалили цю відповідь?

Comment: @P.Vowk відповідь без точної відповіді. Відновити відповідь?

Comment: Як на мене, вона додає інформації до іншої відповіді, тож чому ні?